# Yahoo YQL finance API - prices without tickers

Tags: php, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I'm having a play with the YQL Yahoo finance API and have managed to get json quotes in php.
One thing I've noticed is that not everything has a yahoo ticker, but yahoo still has a page for the security. E.g. PIMCO unconstrained bond fund has the symbol [`pubax`](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=PUBAX&ql=1) which is a standard quote page. However, M&G Strat Bond fund doesn't seem to have a yahoo ticker but is identified by its ISIN code instead, [`GB0033828137.L`](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GB0033828137.L&ql=0).

The format of the url to visit the quotes page of both securities is the same with the `s` parameter in the url being the ticker or the isin.

Now, regarding the YQL API. If I run a query like:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("pubax")
```

I get results as expected. See [test console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22pubax%22%29)

However, if I run the same query using an ISIN of a security without a ticker:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("GB0033828137.L")
```

The results array contains null values and `Ticker not available` error is raised. [See console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22GB0033828137.L%22%29)

Is there a way to get quotes from yahoo using ISIN in cases where a ticker is non-existant?

**EDIT**

This issue also occurs with the csv API:

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=pubax,GB0033828137.L&f=d1l1&e=.csv